# On Kellner's result and the Erdos-Moser equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $m, k$ be positive integers. Consider the Erdos-Moser expression $S_{k}(m) = 1^k + 2^k + ... + (m-1)^k$. By a result of Kellner, we know that if $m | S_{k}(m)$, then $m|B_k$, where $B_r$ denotes the $r-$th Bernoulli number.

**Question:** *Since $B_k$ is not an integer for any even $k$, does Kellner's result entail that $k$ must be odd if $m | S_{k}(m)$ ?*

PS: If the answer to the above question is "yes", it would follow that if $S_{k}(m)=am^k$ for some integer $a$, then $k=1=a$ (the generalised Erdos-Moser conjecture).

Here is a reference to Kellner's result: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_3122423/component/file_3122424/content&ved=2ahUKEwigtZns2dXnAhUJ8hQKHXvFBsk4ChAWMAN6BAgCEAE&usg=AOvVaw2raZVEqq9tXOsT1cH4P5S8